# Issue With the request for IP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-athena, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-elb

My AWS web servers are not showing a request for example '42.26.32.120'
Is there a way to see if our ALB has received a request from that?
We are unable to identify the cause of the issue, as the IPs is not in any of the access logs
Therefore, I am trying to find out where the request was lost.

I found some output against there queries

```
SELECT * FROM alb_logs
WHERE client_ip= '42.26.32.120'
```

but from the results This seems to indicate that after the new app launch ip haven't been able to connect ?

**would that be behavior if clients had written our ALB location statically ?**

and If the request just hung in ALB would it log
e.g. if it couldnt find target machine, or if ALB was no longer around
would we have logs in those cases ?

Any Short of help would be apricated.

Comment: if you're using ALB access logging to s3 you can query it with Athena and if you cant't find that IP with a valid query, it's reasonable to conclude it hasn't made a request.  If you're using app level logs it's possible the IP's request(s) couldn't make it through the load balancer and thus your application might never see it to log.

Comment: ok , Can we go with https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-analyze-access-logs/ or any specific advise form your end ?

Comment: That's a great link, it's what I use to generate the table in athena.  If you have a lot of  logs you can change the path to have a prefix with year/month/day/ to narrow it down some

Comment: Thanks @ erik258 its works , Against Athena queries, I found some new results in alb-logs.

Comment: I did check the logs , Form the ALB logs results this seems to indicate that after the new app launch (new website) this ip haven't been able to connect? I want to know Would that is this behavior if clients had written our ALB location statically? and If the request just hung in ALB would it log it?